# Ambiguous conditions in piecewise function solved by using Sympy

Tags: arguments, sympy, piecewise

I am solving an improper integral using Sympy and it returns a piecewise function as follows.

```
`t= sm.symbols('t', real  = True)
c = sm.symbols('c', real = True)
sol = sm.integrate(sm.exp(c*t), (t, 0, sm.oo))`
```

The results is:

```
Piecewise((-1/c, Abs(arg(c) + pi) < pi/2), (Integral(exp(c*t), (t, 0, oo)), True))
```

But I could not workout if the condition against first function (where it is converging) is true. I know integrand converges for negative values of 'c' but if I use any negative value of 'c' in above inequality, Abs(arg(c) + pi) < pi/2), the answer is always 'False' which should not be the case.

Checked on Sympy by solving the inequality.